# How to reference / insert the IDs inserted in the last two insert statements within the same Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure that is inserting values based off a cursor that I wrote. I am trying to put in a calculated value summed by day. However, (I looked online and couldn't find any examples that do this); how do I reference a previously generated ID (both for Value and Calculation) that are both generated by a trigger?

I was thinking of possibly using a select from the table with the query pulling the most recent id from both tables? I was thinking that that may be too easy to be correct though.

This is my code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROC IS
  Cursor c1 is
    SELECT   SUM(v.value_tx)  AS sum_of_values ,
             e.entity_id      AS entity_id ,
             e.entity_name_tx AS entity_name ,
             e.ei_id_tx       AS ei_id ,
             v.create_dt      AS create_dt ,
             v.hr_num         AS hr_num ,
             v.utc_offset ,
             v.data_date ,
             v.hr_utc ,
             v.hr ,
             ff.form_field_id,
             s.survey_respondent_id,
             v.data_code ,
             'N' AS processed
    FROM     value v
    join     submission_value sv
    ON       v.value_id = sv.value_id
    join     form_field ff
    ON       sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
    join     submission s
    ON       sv.submission_id = s.submission_id
    join     survey_respondent sr
    ON       s.survey_respondent_id = s.survey_respondent_id
    join     entity e
    ON       sr.entity_id = e.entity_id
    WHERE    ei_id_tx IN ('ABC', 'ZYX', 'ADA', 'AZL', 'BAN', 'CAB')
    AND      ff.form_field_id IN ('55', '77')
    GROUP BY e.entity_id,
             e.entity_name_tx,
             e.ei_id_tx,
             v.create_dt,
             v.hr_num,
             v.utc_offset,
             v.data_date,
             v.hr_utc,
             v.hr,
             v.data_code;
     l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
      OPEN c1;

    LOOP
  FETCH c1 into l_var;
  EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    insert into value (product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt)
                  Values ('77', '555', 'NA', l_var.sum_of_values, l_var.utc_offset, l_var.data_date, l_var.hr_utc, l_var.hr, l_var.hr_num, l_var.data_code, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null);
    insert into calculation (survey_respondent_id, calculation_dt, calculation_name_tx, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt, publication_issue_id, entity_survey_id)
                   Values   (l_var.survey_respondent_id, sysdate, sysdate, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null, null, null); 
    insert into calculation_value (calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_Dt, inactive_dt)
                   Values ( ??, ??, l_var.form_field_id, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null);

    END LOOP;
      CLOSE c1;
END TEST_PROC;

*Calculation Table*
Calculation_ID   Survey_Respondent_ID Calculation_Dt Calculation_Name 
Create_Dt Create_User_id

 *Value Table*
 Value_Id     Value       Data_Date     HR     Data_Code   Create_Dt  ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I understand completly, but maybe this is what you are looking for? I may have typed it wrong.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROC IS      
  Cursor c1 is
    SELECT   SUM(v.value_tx)  AS sum_of_values ,
             e.entity_id      AS entity_id ,
             e.entity_name_tx AS entity_name ,
             e.ei_id_tx       AS ei_id ,
             v.create_dt      AS create_dt ,
             v.hr_num         AS hr_num ,
             v.utc_offset ,
             v.data_date ,
             v.hr_utc ,
             v.hr ,
             ff.form_field_id,
             s.survey_respondent_id,
             v.data_code ,
             'N' AS processed
    FROM     value v
    join     submission_value sv
    ON       v.value_id = sv.value_id
    join     form_field ff
    ON       sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
    join     submission s
    ON       sv.submission_id = s.submission_id
    join     survey_respondent sr
    ON       s.survey_respondent_id = s.survey_respondent_id
    join     entity e
    ON       sr.entity_id = e.entity_id
    WHERE    ei_id_tx IN ('ABC', 'ZYX', 'ADA', 'AZL', 'BAN', 'CAB')
    AND      ff.form_field_id IN ('55', '77')
    GROUP BY e.entity_id,
             e.entity_name_tx,
             e.ei_id_tx,
             v.create_dt,
             v.hr_num,
             v.utc_offset,
             v.data_date,
             v.hr_utc,
             v.hr,
             v.data_code;
     l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
     v_value_id value.value_id%type;
     v_calculation_id calculation.calculation_id%type;
    BEGIN
      OPEN c1;

    LOOP
  FETCH c1 into l_var;
  EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    insert into value (value_id,product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt)
                  Values (null,'77', '555', 'NA', l_var.sum_of_values, l_var.utc_offset, l_var.data_date, l_var.hr_utc, l_var.hr, l_var.hr_num, l_var.data_code, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null)
     returning value_id into v_value_id;
    insert into calculation (calculation_id,survey_respondent_id, calculation_dt, calculation_name_tx, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt, publication_issue_id, entity_survey_id)
                   Values   (null,l_var.survey_respondent_id, sysdate, sysdate, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null, null, null)
    returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;               
    insert into calculation_value (calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_Dt, inactive_dt)
                   Values ( v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.form_field_id, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null);

    END LOOP;
      CLOSE c1;
END TEST_PROC;
```

Comment: Thanks! and hmm... that doesn't seem to compile. but what that is supposed to do is what i was looking for.  I get the following errors: Error(53,19): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VALUE_ID" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ;                                               
 Error(53,19): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CALCULATION_ID" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ;

Comment: can you maybe edit the question and write down what the structure of the table value and calculation is? I edited it , maybe try again....

Comment: added the tables with the column names :) and yeah im still getting teh same issue :( it says that oracle was expecting a ':=.(@' instead of the symbol 'VALUE_ID' and 'CALCULATION_ID'

Comment: same error. the version that is in there right now right? it's probably something really minor that we are both missing .... :(

Comment: try again. I moved the declarition of the two variables bellow the cursor.

Comment: hm I did find a typo, I had two ";"

Comment: haha, i didn't copy and paste, i just added what you suggested so i can also gain an understanding of what is going on.

Comment: I found the error. thanks so much for your help. I was the source of the issue, i forgot to take out the semi colon after the 'values' part of the insert statements. thanks so much! and sorry!